# Firebase Child Event Listener to every child last node

Tags: android, firebase, event-listener

I could not figure out how to point my value listener to every child's last node as shown in this picture.

[image: img]

I think I need to use childevent listener but I don't know how to redirect it correctly.

```
Query searchItemQuery = userDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid());
searchItemQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
    @Override
    public onChildAdded, onChildChanged, onChildRemoved, onChildMoved, onCancelled
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that down for each `item0001`, `item0002`, instead of using firebase push id, you can store the `unix timestamp in millis`. That way you can easily sort your entries and get last child node for each item.

So, with this change your database would look like

```
root
  user
    uid
      item0001
         15089344450000 // this is a timestamp
            itemdepositdate
            itemwithdrawdate

         15989922000000 // another timestamp
            itemdepositdate
            itemwithdrawdate

     item0002
```

AND SO ON...

Now, for each item, you can point to last child simply by using below code.

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference()
            .child("root")
            .child("user")
            .child("user_id_of_user")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        snapshot.getRef().orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                 
                                dataSnapshot.getValue(); // this is the last itemdepositdate and itemwithdrawaldate for this item
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: As @uguboz mentions that firebase push keys are already chronological based on timestamp, you can directly run the code without modifying the database and it will serve your need. However, if you have time, I would suggest you to modify your database, because then it will be much easier for you to propogate down the items since you know the key.

Comment: thank you, it works as expected, I follow your answer using the valueeventlistener instead of childeventlistener, thank you so much

Comment: No problem Sir !! My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Query searchItemQuery = userDatabaseReference
                .child(user.getUid)
                .orderByKey() //order nodes w.r.t. the keys
                .limitToLast(1); //gets last item
```

Comment: this will only retrieve the child node at item10001 or will retrieve the child node of item10001,item10002 and so on ?

Comment: sorry i missed the point that it must be in a loop. But the main idea is to get the last node is to use limitToLast(n) for getting n last items. you can adapt code to iterate all item1000x nodes and fetch the last items of each.

Comment: how would orderByKey() work for random push ids generated by firebase ?

Comment: push() keys are generated based on timestamp so last generated value will be ordered as the last item. refer to the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) for details